# React state updates incorrectly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, state, react-props

**Expected:** I am trying to access state data in a variable and manipulate the variable. and again I will setstate the maniplated date into setstate.

**Issue:** when I assign a a state to a variable, instead of just copying the data in the state it becomes duplicate of the state itself, hence when I manipulate the data state itself is changes.

Note: in the below code, `tmpData.splice` is where state changes when I change the `tmpData` variable.

```
onRowAdd: newData => new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        {
        const { data } = this.state;
        const tmpData = data;
        const tmpRowData = this.getRowData(this.state.valorenVal ? this.state.valorenVal : newData.nr ? newData.nr : '');
        if (tmpRowData.length >= 1) {
            if (newData.number && tmpRowData[0].nr) {
                tmpRowData[0].number = newData.number ? newData.number : '';

                tmpData.splice(tmpData.length, 0, tmpRowData[0]);

                this.setState({ data: tmpData }, () => resolve());
                this.setState({ valorenVal: '' });
            } else {
                this.setState({ data }, () => resolve());
            }
        } else {
            this.setState({ data }, () => resolve());
        }
        }
        resolve();
    }, 1000);
}),
```

I'm new to React, this may be a silly issue but your answer will help me understand React better.

Answer (score 2):

In React, you need avoid [direct state mutations](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/handling-state-in-react-four-immutable-approaches-to-consider-d1f5c00249d5/), as it prevents React from accurately tracking the changes that occur. Assuming `data` is an array, you can create a copy of it like this:

```
const tmpData = [...data];
```

or

```
const tmpData = Array.from(data);
```

And edit it as much as you need without causing unwanted mutations before updating the state with `setState`

Answer (score 1):

`tmpData` is a shallow copy of `data`. Since the reference from `tmpData` is maintained from `data` via a shallow copy, that’s why you are still mutating `data`.

Try the following:

```
const tmpData = data.slice()
```

That creates a new array, that should break references to the original array, allowing you to do what you would like to create the next state of `data`. Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

React use shallow compare to check on whether the current props and nextProps objects as well as the current state and nextState objects are equal. It means if all keys in the state have the same value, React will never re-render the component.

In your code `tmpData` is equal to `data`, both of them are the index of the same Object.

```
function shallowEqual(state, nextState) {
    if ( state === nextState) {
        return true; 
    }

    return Object.keys(state).every(key => state[key] === nextState[key]);
}
```